# Error de protocolo SSL desconocido en la conexión con mercadopago PHP

Tags: php, mercadopago, ssl

Utilicé en un tiempo mercadopago y corrió perfectamente en mi sitio, pero después me sale un error de conexión: "'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.mercadopago.com:443". No sé si es un tema de curl o de código que esta mal implementado. Sin embargo como dije, hace dias funcionaba...

Mi codigo es sencillo:

```
<?
include_once('lib/mercadopago.php');
$mp = new MP('APP...');
$mp->sandbox_mode(FALSE);
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => (string) $name,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "currency_id" => "ARG",
            "unit_price" => (float) $price,
        )
    ),
    "external_reference" => 'REFERENCE_' . $id,
);
$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
$payment_button = '<a href="'.$preference["response"]["init_point"].'" target="_blank" title="'.$la['PURCHASE'].'"><i class="purchase"></i></a>';
echo $payment_button;
?>
```

Mi version de ['ssl_version'] es:

```
protocol: OpenSSL/0.9.8zf
```

Y el curl es:

```
7.42.1
```

Podrian decirme de donde viene el error, no sé mucho sobre esto y no consigo informacion... :( Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy teniendo exactamente el mismo problema. En algunos foros dice que tenes que poner la siguiente linea:

```
curl_setopt( $connect, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3' );
```

En el archivo mercadopago.com (en la linea 472 aproximadamente).

¿Encontraste otra forma de solucionarlo? ¿Todavia tenes el problema?

Saludos

Comment: No, aun no encuentro la solución. Pero leí que debo actualizar el PHP de 5.6 para arriba o algo asi, ya que SSLv3 no es seguro según lo que leí y debe usar TLS...